# Issues with Torque Distribution in State-dependent Differential Riccati Equation (SDRE) Controller for 4W SSMR Trajectory Tracking

Tags: control, dynamics, torque, tracking

I am currently working on implementing a State-dependent Differential Riccati Equation Controller (SDRE) to track the trajectory of a 4-wheel skid steer mobile robot (SSMR), where torque serves as the control input. I'm utilizing MATLAB for scripting and testing via a moving box simulation, based on the methods outlined in [this detailed article](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s12206-016-0850-x.pdf).

I encountered some problems regarding the torque distribution when aiming to move the robot in a straight line. Conventionally, for a straight trajectory, the torques applied to the left and right wheel pairs should exhibit equal magnitudes but opposite signs. The dynamics equation, including the control law "u," is represented as follows

$$
\dot{x} = \left[\begin{matrix}
Sv \\
(S^TMS)\text{ \ }(u - S^TM\dot{S}v - S^Tc) \end{matrix}\right] (1)
$$

Where:

$$
\dot{x}: \left[\begin{matrix}
\dot{x}_c \\
\dot{y}_c \\
\dot{\phi}_r \\
\dot{\phi}_l \\
d\dot{\phi}_r \\
d\dot{\phi}_l\end{matrix}\right]
$$

- $S$: Rotation matrix
- $M$: Mass and moment of inertia matrix
- $\dot{S}$: Time derivative of the rotation matrix
- $v$: Angular velocity of right and left side wheel pairs (which is kept constant at 1.538 rad/s).
- $c$: Centripetal Coriolis force vector
- $u$: Control input derived from the control law  ($u=-R\text{ \ }(B^TK(\text{Error})$), details can be found in the above article.

In the dynamics equation (1), the terms $\left[- S^TM\dot{S}v - S^Tc\right]$ have the value of [1.0e-05*0.1859; -1.0e-05*0.1859], when I move the robot with 0.2 m/s to track a straight line which means the control law "u" has to overcome this dynamics resistance to make the robot move and control law u successfully produce the values which are almost equal to zero [0.0023;-0.0024] that remains same almost throughout the iteration loop, which means we need to apply this amount of torque on both side wheels to make the robot move(please see "Controller performance on MATLAB Simulation"). But realistically it is impossible that the robot will move with this amount of torque. My question is: Why do the dynamics terms in equation (1) have an insignificant effect when the robot velocity remains constant throughout (0.2m/s)?
[Controller performance on MATLAB Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgwg6.png).

Upon incorporating resistive forces into the dynamics equation, represented by dynamics equation (1) such as:

$$
\dot{x} = \left[\begin{matrix}
Sv \\
(S^TMS)\text{ \ }(S^TEu - S^TM\dot{S}v - S^Tc - \text{Res})\end{matrix}\right]
$$
Where "Res" denotes the resistive forces computed from [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5702184), with a resultant value of [3.5250; -3.5250]N. Consequently, the control law "u" adeptly compensated for these resistive forces, generating torque values matching their effect [[Figure 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exwPS.png), which are equal to the effect of resistive forces.

However, when considering circular trajectory tracking, where the outer wheels rotate faster than the inner wheels and hence should require a higher torque value than the inner wheels, the model and controller behavior suggest that the entire dynamics have negligible impact on the final torque value. This raises doubts about the accuracy of the dynamics model or potential issues with the controller?
Though the plots show the robot is tracking the reference trajectory but this controller does not work on a physical simulation environment such as V-REP.

I would greatly appreciate your insights on this matter. Thank you for your valuable feedback.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* MUHAMMAD SAQIB. I'm having a hard time following along with the question statement here. You give a state vector of six terms, but you talk about dynamics and give two values. You state that *torque* is the control input to your system, but then there's extensive discussion about trajectory planning and no mention of how the trajectory is converted to a torque reference.

Comment: There's a question about why the dynamics terms are insignificant, but I'm not positive the dynamics terms you're calculating are representing the entire system. Once you get to steady state, the only torque necessary is the torque required to balance any losses; this keeps the net torque zero which keeps the net acceleration zero, which maintains steady state. I can't tell for sure though if your question is just "why are the calculated losses small" or if there's something more, but again you mention a torque input but your plots also show a reference trajectory and reference velocity.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to include more details of the complete controller. Are you converting a trajectory to a reference velocity and converting that to a reference torque? Is there something else happening? Please also *edit your question* to more clearly state the specific problem you're facing. My guess is you're missing an [integral action](https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=MotorPosition&section=ControlStateSpace#15) term, as observed by the steady-state non-zero error in the bottom-left of your [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exwPS.png), but it's just a guess.